# Difference between LTRIM and LTRIM with RTRIM

Tags: sql, sql-server

what's difference between `LTRIM(str)` and `LTRIM(RTRIM(str))`

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM('     Removes trailing spaces.   '))
SELECT LTRIM('     Removes trailing spaces.   ')
```

Comment: What happens when you run the queries?

Comment: it's equals together

Comment: Seems like this would easy enough for you to test. Or, if not, read the documentation on the 2 (very similar) functions.

Comment: LTRIM trims to the left, RTRIM to the right. LTRIM and RTRIM together trim both ways...

Comment: *"it's equals together "* SQL Server ignores trailing spaces when determining equality. `'Trailing Spaces' = 'Trailing Spaces         '` would return `True`. But that isn't what you're asking about here.

Comment: @Larnu .i am get `len(LTRIM(RTRIM('     Removes trailing spaces.   ')))` and `len(LTRIM('     Removes trailing spaces.   ')` . is equals.

Comment: From my comment, @A.R.SEIF ... *"SQL Server ignores trailing spaces when determining equality."**

Comment: and also, `LEN()` excludes trailing spaces for detmining string length https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the question the OP asks in their question, but in the comments, but sounds like it's their real question. I am therefore putting this in as an answer for posterity:

> I am get `len(LTRIM(RTRIM('     Removes trailing spaces.   '))) and len(LTRIM('     Removes trailing spaces.   ')` . is equals.

When determining equality SQL Server ignores trailing spaces. `'Trailing Spaces' = 'Trailing Spaces         '` would return `True`.

This is *not* the case for leading spaces. `' Leading Space' = 'Leading Space'` would **not** return `True`.

Thus, when comparing 2 values, if they might have varying numbers of leading spaces, you would need to trim (`LTRIM`) those, but for comparison purposes (only) you would not need to trim (`RTRIM`) the trailing ones.

Of course, you could trim both with `TRIM` in more recent versions of SQL Server (2017+), however, any trim operations will make your query non-SARGable, which could (significantly) effect performance. If you need to store untrimmed and trimmed data, you are better off with the latter being a `PERSISTED` computed column you can index.

Answer (score 2):

`ltrim()` removes leading spaces from the string (spaces on the left side), `rtrim()` removes the trailing spaces.

Cascading the two functions removes spaces on both ends. Some (many... most!) databases have a generic `trim()` function; SQL server 2017 onwards has this function, but older versions do not: that's the reason why you will sometimes meet this `ltrim(rtrim(...))` construct in legacy code.

Comment: *"not SQL Server:"* Check again: [TRIM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @A.R.SEIF see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64677094/difference-between-ltrim-and-ltrim-with-rtrim#comment114357673_64677094) when you mentioned about that in the questions's comments, however, again, that isn't the problem you ask about in the question. If that *is* what you're asking you should be asking that in the question.

Comment: @Larnu: thanks, I did not know that! I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I admit, it wasn't one of the biggest selling points of SQL Server 2017, @GMB . :)